# One shower doesn't work and the fridge either

Tags: grammaticality

> One shower doesn't work and the fridge either.

Is it well said? One shower and the fridge doesn't work.

Comment: How many showers are there?

Comment: One shower doesn't work, nor does the fridge.

Comment: One shower, and the shower doesn't work!

Comment: @HotLicks. I like your suggestion best, so far (though I might write it with a semicolon). Why not promote it to an answer?

Comment: I don't do answers.  And as "nor" is arguably a conjunction, the use of a semicolon would seem to be inappropriate.

Comment: For me, the simplest change to make this idiomatically correct would be "One shower doesn't work, and the fridge doesn't either." Note that "one shower doesn't" implies that there's at least one other shower which does, and "the fridge" implies that there is _not_ another refrigerator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the expression *one shower* to refer to one of the showers is not actually a good idea. The expression *one of the showers* would be more natural as it contains an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29), *the*, which creates a sense of specification and therefore makes the sentence sound a lot more idiomatic.

---

I'd prefer to use *neither* in this case.

> One of the showers doesn't work and neither does the fridge.

or

> Neither one of the showers nor the fridge works.

If I am to use *either*, I would use a comma to separate it from the rest of the sentence.

> One of the showers doesn't work, and the fridge doesn't, either.

Comment: "Neither one shower" is a bit awkward/confusing. Otherwise, good suggestions.

Comment: @KyleStrand The expression *one of the showers* is definitely more idiomatic than that but for some reasons I have decided not to paraphrase OP's expressions too much. A bad decision indeed.

Comment: _"Neither one of the showers"_ sounds like _"none of the two showers"_ to me. Moreover, unless I'm mistaken, it does actually mean _"none of the two showers"_.

Comment: "***Neither one of the showers nor the fridge works.***" -- that just doesn't sound right to my ear. I don't think it is acceptable (except, maybe, for linguists doing exercises).

Comment: @MrLister True. Having the expression *one of the showers* preceded by *neither* creates confusion in the syntax of the sentence at first glance (Actual structure: "neither *X* nor *Y* ...". The structure appears to be at first glance: "neither one of *X's* ...." [but this interpretation of the syntax would not make much sense later on due to the conjunction *nor* after the subject - a suggestion that this is not the end of the constituent] ),

Comment: and this is probably the reason why the sentence doesn't sound right to @F.E.

Answer (score 8):

I'd swap it round, seems better that way

> The fridge doesn't work and neither does one of the showers.

then I'd go on to say

> Frankly, this isn't good enough

Comment: Maybe good enough if you're buying, but certainly not if you're looking to rent.

Comment: The wording of each phrase is good. You could keep the original order, though, and the sentence would still be about equally good: "One of the showers doesn't work, and neither does the fridge."

Comment: I don't like this wording: "neither does one of the showers" is a bit vague between "there is not one shower that works" and "there is one shower that does not work".

Comment: ^ agree, this sounds ambiguous, possibly as "neither does (any) one of the showers"; but I'm afraid I haven't the background to identify why this order is less definite.

Answer (score 5):

The meaning is a small bit ambiguous in your sentence. Put in another "doesn't" to make it clear what you mean:

> One shower doesn't work and the fridge doesn't either.

So then it's "...the fridge doesn't (work) either."

Answer (score 0):

You actually only need to add a single letter to make it correct. Add an 'n' in front of 'either' to make it 'neither', so that it reads:

'One shower doesn't work and the fridge **neither**.'

Comment: This is incorrect. _Neither_ is the negating form of _either_; the negative verbal _doesn't_ is inferred by _fridge_, so the last part of the sentence (with _neither_) is the equivalent of "... and the fridge doesn't neither." This both sounds wrong and uses a double negative, which is not valid in English. One could use _neither_ if the positive _does_ is specified (as other answers have suggested): "... and neither does the fridge."

Comment: @iamnotmaynard My sense is that I am saying 'The shower doesn't work; and the fridge does neither', with the 'does' elided. (Note I have now placed a semi-colon between the two clauses.)  But you may be right. Shall we pose it as a question to see what others think?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a more positive form, which feels less awkward in my opinion:

> One of the showers is broken, and so is the fridge.

Or:

> The fridge is broken, and so is one of the showers.

Answer (score 0):

Both the fridge and the shower are broken.